# How to access Face Manipulation Mode?

Tags: simulation, blender, hotkeys, figures

I am fairly new to Blender and I am trying to join objects together on blender for a simulation. I have researched for an answer, and have found one source which seemed to work best with what I was trying to do. I have been using the answer given on [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33843/how-to-merge-two-objects-in-blender). I have switched to object mode, selected the objects, and pressed Ctrl+J to join the objects. I am then supposed to enter Edit Mode, and then Face Manipulation Mode. I do not know how to access Face Manipulation Mode, or Vertex Manipulation Mode, and cannot find any online resource to show me how to access it. Does someone know what hot keys I can press/ tabs I can open to get to this?

[image]

Comment: [The blender wiki has tutorial links](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Resources/External_links) that includes basic introductions to blender that explain these options.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tab key to switch between object mode and edit mode.

"Face manipulation" mode is not really a thing, just select a face (RMB while in edit mode) and manipulate it just like anything else.  Make sure that the face selection is enabled (three little buttons on the horizontal bar below the 3d view let you modify the selection possibilities to vertex, edges, and/or faces.   (They look like icons with selected those-things on them, respectively)